# TortoiseGit commands not available in Total Commander

Tags: tortoisegit, total-commander

I have weird problem with TortoiseGit in Total Commander. Suddenly I can't use TortoiseGit commands in Total Commander because they disappeared from context menu. But they still work in Windows Explorer. I have already tried to reinstall/repair TortoiseGit, reinstall Total Commander, run TC as administrator but nothing helped.

I have Windows 7 Professional SP1, TortoiseGit-1.8.16.0-64bit, TC 8.52a 64 bit (2015-09-17).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to TortoiseGit settings -> Icon overlays and make sure "Show context menu overlay only in explorer" is not checked.

Comment: I was just going crazy when I found your easy and helpful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Total Comander
Configuration -> Options... -> Icons
check "Show overlay icons"